# My code is giving a wrong answer in codechef

Tags: java, error-handling, compiler-errors

My code works fine in my compiler and I even tried another few online compilers but still not able to find the issue, can someone help!

**Question**

https://www.codechef.com/JUNE18B/problems/NAICHEF

Once, after a stressful day, Chef decided to relax and visit a casino near his house to gamble. He feels lucky and he's going to bet almost all of his money.

The game Chef is going to play in the casino consists of tossing a die with N
 faces twice. There is a number written on each face of the die (these numbers are not necessarily distinct). In order to win, Chef must get the number A
 on the first toss and the number B
 on the second toss of the die.

The excited viewers want to know the probability that Chef will win the game. Can you help them find that number? Assume that Chef gets each face of the die with the same probability on each toss and that tosses are mutually independent.

[image: question1]
[image: question2]

**My submission**

```
import static java.lang.System.exit;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

/**
 *
 * @author williamscott
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean status = true;

        int T = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

        //Original Constraint
        if (T < 1 || T > 10) {
//            System.out.println("Please follow original constraint for T");
//            exit(0);
            status = false;
        }

        int N[] = new int[T], A[] = new int[T], B[] = new int[T];
        float Probability[] = new float[T];

        for (int t = 0; t < T; t++) {

            String[] input = in.nextLine().split(" ");

            N[t] = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);
            A[t] = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
            B[t] = Integer.parseInt(input[2]);

            if (N[t] < 1 || N[t] > 100) {
//                System.out.println("Please follow original constraint for N");
//                exit(0);
                status = false;
            }

            if (A[t] < 1 || A[t] > N[t]) {
//                System.out.println("Please follow original constraint for A");
//                exit(0);
                status = false;

            }

            if (B[t] < 1 || B[t] > N[t]) {
//                System.out.println("Please follow original constraint for B");
//                exit(0);
                status = false;
            }

            float pn, pa = 0, pb = 0;

            String[] f = in.nextLine().split(" ");
            pn = f.length;

            if (pn != N[t]) {
//                System.out.println("Inputs Invalid");
//                exit(0);
                status = false;
            }

            for (String f1 : f) {

                if (Integer.parseInt(f1) < 1 || Integer.parseInt(f1) > N[t]) {
//                    System.out.println("Please follow original constraint for x (input)");
//                    exit(0);
                    status = false;
                }

                if (Integer.parseInt(f1) == A[0]) {
                    pa++;
                }
                if (Integer.parseInt(f1) == B[0]) {
                    pb++;
                }
            }

            Probability[t] = (pa / pn) * (pb / pn);
        }

        if (status) {
            for (float d : Probability) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%.10f", d));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Error:**
[image: Error Image]

Comment: Post both the relevant part of the assignment as well as your code into the question plus a clear description for what input your code outputs the wrong result and what the correct one is supposed to be.

Comment: @luk2302 thank you for the quick response, i updated the question...

Comment: Thank you for your question improvements -- down-vote and close-vote removed. I don't have time to go through the code, but several suggestions: avoid doing `==` and `!=` with floating point numbers since these sort of comparisons don't work well with inexact representations that floating points are. Instead those numbers probably should be ints. you'll want to convert them to double when you do the divisions in your probability calculations by casting, but leave them as ints until you absolutely need doubles.

Comment: Also as an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: Also **never** use float when double will work. Otherwise you lose much precision with little gain.

Comment: You also look to be over-complicating your code quite a bit. Simplify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should use double rather then float (precision matters)!

Secondly, you should update your conditions for status because you take in consideration only the first sub-task with (T less than 10, and N less than 100) which will give you only 20 points! the second sub-task (that rewards 80 points) takes a T less than 70 and a N less than 1000.

Finally, the issue with the code comes from the condition of updating pa & pb, you use  :

```
    Integer.parseInt(f1) == A[0]  // same for B[0]
```

instead of

```
    Integer.parseInt(f1) == A[t]  // same for B[t]
```

Here is the complete code and submission results

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.*;

    /**
     *
     * @author aoubidar
     */
    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            // number of test cases
            int T = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());


            int[] N = new int[T];
            int[] A = new int[T];
            int[] B = new int[T];

            double[] Probability = new double[T];

            for (int t = 0; t < T; t++) {

                String[] input = in.nextLine().split(" ");

                N[t] = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);
                A[t] = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
                B[t] = Integer.parseInt(input[2]);

                int total, pa = 0, pb = 0 ;

                String[] faces = in.nextLine().split(" ");
                total = faces.length;

                for (String f : faces) {

                    if (Integer.parseInt(f) == A[t]) {
                        pa++;
                    }
                    if (Integer.parseInt(f) == B[t]) {
                        pb++;
                    }
                }

                double pn = (double) (total * total);

                Probability[t] = (pa * pb) / pn ;
            }

            for (double d : Probability) {
                System.out.println(d);
            }


        }

    }
```

submission success:
[image: submission succes]

Comment: Very nice catch and explanation. 1+ to this answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, a little while back I figured this one out and I was about to post my final answer... and I completely forgot to post the answer getting involved in another question.
your suggestion "Also never use float when double will work. Otherwise, you lose much precision with little gain." helped, and i actually noticed that float giving inaccurate values.

i changed it to float and tested and i figured the loop count change too...

Thanks a lot once again...

Answer (score 2):

1. **Never** compare floating point numbers using `==` or `!=`. Digital computers cannot represent floating point numbers with absolute precision, and so these tests will often fail.
2. **Never** use `float` when `double` will work. You gain little by using float and lose a much precision.
3. Leave your integer input as `int`s, and convert to `double` only when needed, here cast to `double` when doing probability calculations
4. Don't over-complicate your code as you're doing, and use testable methods to help simplify as well.  No need to use arrays for example. The constraints mentioned above likely do not need to be tested in your program but rather assumed to be true.
5. Use variable names that comply with Java naming standards, and that make sense.

For example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // get number of trys
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        int trys = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
        for (int i = 0; i < trys; i++) {
            // for each try, calc probability
            double probability = processTry(scanner);
            System.out.println(probability);
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    private static double processTry(Scanner scanner) {
        String line;
        // get first line
        line = scanner.nextLine();

        // use Scanner to get ints from line
        Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);

        //number of faces
        int numberOfFaces = lineScan.nextInt();
        int a = lineScan.nextInt();
        int b = lineScan.nextInt();
        lineScan.close();

        // scanner to get face values
        line = scanner.nextLine();
        lineScan = new Scanner(line);

        // count of how many faces match a and b values
        int aMatch = 0;
        int bMatch = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
            int face = lineScan.nextInt();
            if (a == face) {
                aMatch++;
            } 
            if (b == face) {
                bMatch++;
            }
        }
        lineScan.close();

        // only cast to double when need for calc
        double probability = ((double) (aMatch * bMatch) / (numberOfFaces * numberOfFaces));
        return probability;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose there is n(A) is the number of occurrence of A on the dice and n(B) is the number of occurrence of B on the dice. In this, the probability that A will be thrown at a given time is

> P(A) = n(A) / N

and the probability that B will be thrown at a given time is

> P(B) = n(B) / N

The probability that A will be thrown first and B will be thrown second is

> P(A) ^ P(B) = P(A) * P(B)

since the experiments are independent.

> P(A) * P(B) = n(A) * n(B) / N^2

since this is precisely in your code, you have implemented a correct algorithm for the calculation, so the problem must consist in something else than the algorithm.

#### Usage of float

The usage of float might be causing slight differences between your result and the expected result. Change it to double.